# (WPF) How do i grab the text of a textbox inside an ItemsControl?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio

This is my ItemsControl in the XAML file:

```
            <ItemsControl x:Name="PNItemsControl">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding TextBoxText}" Width="150"/>
                        <Button Content="Remove" Width="50"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
```

The number of Textboxes I generate varies. I want to grab the text with this code:

```
            string[] phoneNumbers = "";
            foreach(TextBox tb in PNItemsControl.Items.OfType<TextBox>())
            {
                phoneNumbers.Append(tb.Text);
            }
            c.PhoneNumbers = phoneNumbers;
```

But the ItemsControl does not see the textboxes generated. I even tried to grab the buttons or the stackpanels and still the variable (tb in this case stays null). Did I make a mistake or is there an alternative to grab items from ItemsControl?

Comment: "Did I make a mistake?" - you assume that items are TextBoxes. they aren't (if you set up ItemsControl properly). they are objects of some type which has TextBoxText property.

Comment: Thank you very much! I see the problem! I used the variable TextBoxText  when I was binding the ItemsControl and now I use that to grab the text. Fixed the problem!

Comment: @KostasSoulios, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider answering it and accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should loop through `PNItemsControl.Children` which are of type `FrameworkElement` !
So:

```
foreach(FrameworkElement in PNItemsControl.Children)
```

or

```
foreach (var element in PNItemsControl.Children.OfType<FrameworkElement>())
```

from there you should be able to identify your textboxes